# How can I use Double Buffering on TI-84 Plus CE Python Edition?

Tags: python, calculator

I'm making a game on the TI-84 Plus CE Python Edition using Python, but I'm having trouble using double buffering. I know that it is possible because I've played games on the calculator that don't flicker like mine, but I think they're using ez80 assembly, which I would like to avoid.

How can I use Double Buffering on the TI-84 Plus CE Python Edition, ideally without going into ez80 assembly, or if I need to, inline ez80?

I tried find answers online but all I can find are z80/ez80/Ice C solutions, and I would really like to keep my game in Python.

I'm drawing to the screen like this:

```
import ti_graphics as graphics
import ti_system as system

x=100
y=100

#Clear screen and set color to red
graphics.cls()
graphics.setColor((255,0,0))

while True:
  key=system.wait_key()
  #If right arrow pressed
  if key==1:
    x+=1
  
  #The problematic code
  graphics.cls()
  graphics.fillRect(x,y,10,10)
```

When running this code, anytime any key is pressed the screen flashes white and then rectangle is filled in, causing flickering.